How to prove the following partition related identity?
So I want to show that the following is true, but Iam kidna stuck...
$$
\sum_{q_{1}=1}^{\infty}\sum_{q_{2}=q_{1}}^{\infty}\sum_{q_{3}=q_{1}}^{q_{2}}...\sum_{q_{k+1}=q_{1}}^{q_{k}}x^{q_{1}+q_{2}+...+q_{k+1}}=\sum_{q_{1}=1}^{\infty}\sum_{q_{2}=q_{1}}^{\infty}\sum_{q_{3}=q_{2}}^{\infty}...\sum_{q_{k+1}=q_{k}}^{\infty}x^{q_{1}+q_{2}+...+q_{k+1}}
$$
At first I tought something like that:
$$
\sum_{q_{1}=1}^{\infty}\sum_{q_{2}=q_{1}}^{\infty}x^{q_{1}+q_{2}}\prod_{m=3}^{k+1}\sum_{q_{m}=q_{1}}^{q_{m-1}}x^{q_{m}}=\sum_{q_{1}=1}^{\infty}\sum_{q_{2}=q_{1}}^{\infty}x^{q_{1}+q_{2}}\prod_{m=3}^{k+1}\sum_{q_{m}=q_{m-1}}^{\infty}x^{q_{m}}
$$
$$
\prod_{m=3}^{k+1}(\frac{x^{q_{1}}-x^{q_{m-1}+1}}{1-x})=\prod_{m=3}^{k+1}(\frac{x^{q_{m-1}}}{1-x})
$$
$$
\prod_{m=3}^{k+1}(x^{q_{1}-q_{m-1}}-x)=1
$$
but from here on out i dont know how to continue, given that the steps so far were even productive to begin with...
In addition i dont want to use the following Indentity to prove what i have just shown.
$$
\sum_{q_{1}=1}^{\infty}\sum_{q_{2}=q_{1}}^{\infty}\sum_{q_{3}=q_{2}}^{\infty}...\sum_{q_{k+1}=q_{k}}^{\infty}x^{q_{1}+q_{2}+...+q_{k+1}}=\prod_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{x}{1-x^{m}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p_{k+1}(n)x^{n}
$$
Thanks for all the suggestions

So you want to show that for each integer $n$, the number of weakly increasing tuples of positive integers summing to $n$ equals the number of weakly decreasing tuples of integers summing to $n$ (because these are the coefficients of $x^n$ on the two sides of your equality). Do you see a bijection perhaps?

I suggest manually investigating the two specific cases of $~k \in {3,4},~$ to try to determine a pattern in the data.  Then, I suggest using the perceived pattern to formulate a hypothesis for each of the specific cases of $~k \in {3,4}, ~$ and then trying to prove that this hypothesis is true.  Then, I suggest rinsing and repeating for the more general case of $~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 5}}.$

Thx for the suggestions. I'm particularly interested in a bijective proof as proposed by Darij Grinberg, but how would I prove this? How would I show that the sums are injective and surjective? Unfortunately, I only wrote my Abitur last month and won't be studying mathematics until October, so I'm pretty inexperienced. If you (@darijgrinberg) or anyone else could give me any additional guidance or details I would be very grateful. The method suggested by @user2661923 is also promising, I'll check that out.
